# Tightest constant factor for error term of the prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

What are the best known (unconditional) bounds on the following: 
$$\mid\psi(x) - x\mid$$
(With a known constant factor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807), should be available online. You want Theorems 4, 11, 12, 13, 14, pages 70 and 71.